Change configuration for an app registration than for an enterprise application
I have an application running in Azure as an enterprise application and I would like to know how to configure authentication for this type of application. They have provided me with an XML file with the configuration but I don't know how to include it in said configuration. The code I use is the following:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
        options.MetadataAddress = builder.Configuration["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

        // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
        // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL:
        options.Wtrealm = builder.Configuration["ida:Wtrealm"];
          
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true 
        };
    });

For the user to authenticate, is this library worth it or would I need a different SAML client? If so, which SAML client?
Thanks in advance, regards
